# Keycloak occasionally give me an 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: keycloak

I create an admin client for user management;
Here is what my code looks like:

```
    @Bean
Keycloak initKeycloakWithAdminRole() {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(keycloakServerUrl)
            .realm(realm)
            .username(username)
            .password(password)
            .clientId(clientId)
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
            .build();
}
```

The first time I created a user, it was successful； After a while, create a new user again, it returns 401;But I created it and it worked again.

Comment: `401` means [Unauthorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors), so it's not an issue with your bean, but with the controller (and/or access configuration). "After a while" might indicate a session timeout